# How to eliminate duplicate from select query for loop function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am beginner php developer. I have create function for loop get select query from data, I have get multiple select query show same id. How to eliminate the duplicate query?

**Code:**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_group_id']); $i++) {
       $bulk_invoice_id = create_guid();
       $sql = "INSERT INTO ggs_bulk_invoice(id, group_id, service_date, city, service, duration, notes,rate,rate_with_vat, vendor_id,service_meeting_id)"
               . " VALUES('$bulk_invoice_id','{$_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_group_id'][$i]}','{$_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_date'][$i]}','{$_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_city'][$i]}','{$_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_service'][$i]}','{$_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_duration'][$i]}','{$_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_notes'][$i]}' ,'{$_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_rate'][$i]}','{$_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_rate_vat'][$i]}','{$_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_vendor_id'][$i]}','{$_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_meeting_id'][$i]}')";
       $db->query($sql);
       $sql = "INSERT INTO ginvo_client_invoice_ggs_bulk_invoice_1_c(id, ginvo_client_invoice_ggs_bulk_invoice_1ginvo_client_invoice_ida, ginvo_client_invoice_ggs_bulk_invoice_1ggs_bulk_invoice_idb)"
               . " VALUES('" . create_guid() . "','$bean->id','$bulk_invoice_id')";
       $db->query($sql);

       $query = "SELECT DISTINCT ON (id_c) ids_c, service_type_c FROM meetings_cstm WHERE id_c='".$_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_meeting_id'][$i]."'";

       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($query);
       echo "</pre>";

   }
```

Comment: First of all, visit http://bobby-tables.com and learn about SQL injection and how to prevent them. Your code is not safe at all and really vulnerable to injections. Your whole database could be deleted in a few seconds, without any need of deeper knowledge of your system.

Comment: Your second query has an object - `$bean`, and uses `$bean->id` as a value for the insert. Where does `$bean` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Group by `id_c` + `max` (or `min`) on `ids_c` and `service_type_c`

*(you need a rule to chose only one value if you have duplicate)*

```
$query = "SELECT id_c,max(ids_c) as ids_c, max(service_type_c) as service_type_c FROM meetings_cstm WHERE id_c='".$_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_meeting_id'][$i]."' group by id_c";
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the answer you are looking for is to simply store a cache of your IDs as you loop through the array. If a duplicate pops up, simply skip it:

```
$num_entries = count($_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_group_id']);
$cache = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_entries; $i++) {
    if(in_array($_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_group_id'][$i], $cache)) {
        continue;
    }

    $cache[] = $_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_group_id'][$i];

    // More stuff
```

But. You've made many mistakes while writing this code. I shall detail them below:

---

1. Using `$_REQUEST`

`$_REQUEST` contains `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`. In older versions of PHP it also contained `$_FILES`. This is bad as it introduces ambiguity into your code and can cause "gotchas" later. Determine how you are getting the data into your script, and use the appropriate superglobal variable.

---

2. `for ($i = 0; $i < count($_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_group_id']); $i++) {`

The problem with this line here is including the count() function in the `for` declaration itself. That `$i < count($_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_group_id'])` condition gets re-evaluated for every single iteration of the loop - lots of pointless counting!

---

3. `VALUES('$bulk_invoice_id','{$_REQUEST['bulk_invoice_group_id'][$i]}'`

This is perhaps the worst offender. By directly inserting user input into your query, you are exposing yourself to [injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Look into [prepared queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), or (less secure but better than nothing) [escape functions](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

---

4. One lining your SQL

This is more of a pet peeve than anything else, but for some reason I see so many people doing it. **There is no reason to put all your SQL query on a single line**. All you are doing is making your query harder to read and maintain.

This:

`$sql = "insert into tablename (col1, col2, col3) values ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')";`

Could be written as

```
$sql = "
    insert into tablename (
        col1,
        col2,
        col3
    ) values (
        'val1',
        'val2',
        'val3'
    )
";
```

with no impact on performance whatsoever. It's just so much easier to read.